# Reducing number of very long constructor overloads with just a few different parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor

I made custom interface system which uses basic UI controls like button, label, etc. Some controls have many options, so they use long constructors, and they only differ in one or two parameters. And this is work in progress, so I change optional parameters a lot, and it takes quite some time to apply changes to all constructors.

```
public Button(string Text, Rectangle Rect, Texture2D Texture, bool moreStuff)
public Button(string Text, Point Position, Texture2D Texture, bool moreStuff)
public Button(string Text, Vector2 Position, Texture2D Texture, bool moreStuff)
```

I tried using `dynamic` keyword instead of `Rectangle`, `Point` and `Vector2` to decrease the number of constructors, and it compiles, works, and seems ok for the moment. But maybe I'm missing something that might break this approach later?

To find out what was passed as `dynamic Position` I check for `.GetType().Name`, use a switch and throw an exception at `default:` if it wasn't a recognized type.

Is it fine to do it like this, or is there a better (more safe or appropriate) way?

---

Currently it's possible to create a fully customized instance of `Button` inline, and I wouldn't like to lose that ability.

Comment: I would definitely *not* use dynamic in this way; it's only going to make your code worse. Just carefully create as many constructors as you need, with specific types.

Comment: Perhaps use the params keyword? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @RickKuipers `params` is for the same type.. these differ.. unless he uses `object`.. but that would also become a future nightmare.

Comment: @RickKuipers as much as I'd like to make code simpler, using params would seriously decrease readability and I wouldn't know which constructor I'm using.

Comment: An other class with a interface that only contains a func like : 'List<object> GetParams()'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to define constructor arguments if you're finding it tedious. You could use an object initializer quite nicely:

```
SomeButton button = new SomeButton()
{
    Text = "",
    MoreStuff = false
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that is supposed to help me.

Comment: @user1306322 It eliminates the need for all of those complex constructors, entirely.

Comment: How so? I still need to actually pass some arguments to customize the Button. I'd never have any use for a Button with all default field values.

Comment: But then I'd lose the ability to create Button instances in-line.

Comment: `SomeButton button = new SomeButton() { Text = "", MoreStuff = false };` Is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

This calls for a [parameter object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject). That's a class with a property per parameter. Your `Button` constructor would now only take one parameter: That parameter object.

Using `dynamic` to reduce the number of overloads is definitely not the correct approach.

Comment: And then that parameter class would have the same three (actually more) long constructors. The reason those constructors are so long is I'd really like to stay able to create class instances in-line.

Comment: @user1306322: I would create this parameter object as a mutable class. You could then use it like this: `new Button(new ButtonParameters { Text = "foo", Rect= ... });` Even if you would want to make that parameter object immutable, at least the code of your Button class would be a bit cleaner, because it wouldn't contain so many constructors.

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to "compact" thees three Forms constructor parameters??

Comment: I'm looking for a way to reduce the number of constructors while maintaining the readability.

Comment: @user1306322: If you have only one parameter that is different for all constructors you could make your parameter object have all the other parameters. That would give the parameter object exactly one constructor. You would still have three constructors in Button, but each would now only take two parameters: The parameter object and the `Rectangle`, `Vector` or `Point`. Changing any of the parameters contained within the parameter object will now be much easier, because you only have one constructor to change.

Comment: No way. You can not hide the other constructors without a lot of troubles. The only way is the parameter object ( see original post from Daniel Hilgarth )

Answer (score 0):

Using `dynamic` is not appropritate in your scenario. Having differenct constructor overloads is not a bad thing (not worth than abusing the `dynamic` keyword). Many classes in .NET Framework BCL has several constructor overloads (for example, [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) class has 15 contstructors) and some methods has several overload for differenct uses ([`MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx) for example).

Comment: I agree that there's nothing bad in having a dozen constructors, it's just that I add parameters sometimes and it takes some time to update all of them.

Comment: @user1306322 You can omit non-crucial parameters and make them properties.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to type this yourself:

```
class YourPositioningType {
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public static YourPositioningType FromVector(Vector2 vector) {
        return new YourPositioningType() { X = vector.X, Y = vector.Y };
    }

    public static YourPositioningType FromRectangle(Rectangle rect) {
        // etc..
    }
}
```

Static methods to convert from each of the above types. Then you would call it as:

```
Button b = new Button("Blah", YourPositioningType.FromVector(new Vector2() { /* etc */));
```

Then you just use the above class in a single constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you use object initialisers, then you can set each individual property you require independently. You just have to be careful that the various properties can be initialised independently.

For example:

```
public class Button
{
    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return Rectangle.Width;
        }
        set
        {
            Rectangle.Width = value;
        }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return Rectangle.Height;
        }
        set
        {
            Rectangle.Height = value;
        }
    }

    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return Rectangle.Left;
        }
        set
        {
            Rectangle.Left = value;
        }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get
        {
            return Rectangle.Top;
        }
        set
        {
            Rectangle.Top = value;
        }
    }

    public Rectangle Rectangle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

If you had a class like the above, you can do either:

```
var button = new Button
{
    Rectangle = new Rectangle(...)
}
```

or:

```
var button = new Button
{
    Left = 0,
    Top = 0,
    Width = 100,
    Height = 20
}
```

Object initializer notation is ideal for initializing object via their properties where you can have multiple combinations of properties needing to be set.